# モジュールが読み込めないので、Python3でマイニングプールからのハッシュレートをAPIで表示できない

Tags: python3, json, api

困りごとは、表題の通りです。

こちらがやりたいことです。
＊追記：print 文が2系のものになっているという指摘を受けましたが、
どのように修正すれば良いかわかりません。宜しくお願いします

PythonでマイニングプールからのハッシュレートをAPIで取得してJSONから表示

```
#python3

-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
インポートするモジュール*-

import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json
import sys
import codecs


#python3
webAPIからJSONの形式の文字列の結果をもらう
def dataGet():

     URIスキーム
    url = ''

     URIパラメータのデータ 
    param = {
        'address': 'worker',    # 取得したい人のID
        'type': 'json'             # 取得するデータの指定
    }

     webAPIからのJSONを取得
    response = readObj.read()

     print type(response)  # >> <type 'str'>
　
# URIパラメータの文字列の作成
    paramStr = urllib.request(param)  # type=jsonと整形される

    return response

webAPIから取得したデータをJSONに変換する
def jsonConversion(jsonStr):

     webAPIから取得したJSONデータをpythonで使える形に変換する
    data = json.loads(jsonStr)
    return data

     日本語が u'\u767d' のようになってしまうため、Unicodeに変換する
     return json.dumps(data[0], ensure_ascii=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    resStr = dataGet()
    res = jsonConversion(resStr)

    取得したデータを表示する
    for item in res:
        print(item.dataGet())
```

上記のコードを実行したところ、

```
#python3
 File "zec3.py", line 43, in <module>
    resStr = dataGet()
  File "zec3.py", line 25, in dataGet
    paramStr = urllib.request(param) 
  type=jsonと整形される
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

というエラーが表示され、モジュールが読み込めないのは、わかったのですが、
対処の仕方が分かりません。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/158176

Comment: 最終的にやりたいことは「表題の通り」なのかもしれませんが、困りごとは「モジュールが読み込めない」部分かと思うので、こちらを強調するような質問の仕方(タイトル)にすべきかなと思います。 / 何箇所か`#python3`と書かれた行が出てきますが、単なるコメント扱いなのか、分割された複数のファイルなのかが分かりづらいです。可能であればファイル名も説明として追記してもらうと見やすいかなと思います。質問は後からでも [編集] できますのでタイトルと合わせて見直してみてください。

Comment: タイトルを変更しました。また、コメント扱いでPython3で全体を書いています

Comment: コメント文に「URIパラメータの文字列の作成」と書かれていますので、`paramStr = urllib.request(param)` は `paramStr = urllib.parse.urlencode(param)` とするのではないでしょうか。ただ、変数 `paramStr` が他では使われていないのが気になりますが… また、`jsonConversion()` 関数に return 文が2個ありますね(インデントもずれています)。質問欄のコードは元コードの抜粋なのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。引用元のコードがあり、それをカスタマイズしています

Answer (score 0):

## エラーの原因

`urllib.request` はモジュールであるため、 `urllib.request(param)` というような使い方が出来ません。`urllib.request.Request`や`urllib.request.urlopen`を組み合わせてリクエストを実行する必要があります。

## 正しい実装に向けて

ドキュメントを参照するか、比較的扱いやすい`requests`ライブラリを利用して作成し直すことをおすすめします。
[21.6. urllib.request — URL を開くための拡張可能なライブラリ — Python 3.6.5 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/urllib.request.html)
[Requests: HTTP for Humans™ — Requests 2.20.1 documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの記事を参照にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 0):

書き直すと以下のようなコードでAPIを取得できると思います。WebAPIでJSON形式とわかっている場合はurllibで十分対応可能です。

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json

def dataGet():
    # urlは空白だったので適当に書きました
    url = 'https://example.com/api'
    param = {
        'address': 'worker',    # 取得したい人のID
        'type': 'json'             # 取得するデータの指定
    }

    paramStr = urllib.parse.urlencode(param)
    req = urllib.request.Request(f'{url}?{paramStr}')
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
        return json.load(response)

res = dataGet()
#resは、辞書型なのでjsonで整形してからプリントしています。また、`ensure_ascii=False`は、非ASCII文字をエスケープせずにそのまま出力しています。
print(json.dumps(res, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2))
```

Comment: すみません、上記のコードを実践したところ、

Comment: `res = dataGet()
  File "test12.py", line 15, in dataGet
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open`

Comment: `response = meth(req, response)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Comment: 上記のような、エラーが出てきてしまっているという状態です

Comment: 403: Forbidden ということは、相手のサーバーに接続を拒否されています。接続の条件が間違っていると思われるので、APIのマニュアルを十分に読んでください。また、エラーの原因を回答するためには、APIの仕様が必要です。